# How can I keep the styles for different parts of a StyledText widget using Bullets?

Tags: styles, swt, bulletedlist, styledtext

I'm new in the community so looking forward to start participating by both helping and getting help.

Right now I have a problem that maybe someone has already gone through.

I'm trying to have a StyledText widget (SWT) and show the line numbers per each line, but I need those line numbers to have their own style too. 
I haven't been able to get both sections of the widget have two different styles (StyleRanges) as it is only picking up the style associated to the line numbers bullet and completely discarding the style for the actual source code.

Can someone help here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting the StyleRanges?